# Using mutual SSL for secure proxying of requests

Tags: java, security, authentication, ssl

I'm working on a website (A) that's going to proxy requests to/from the other websites (B) plugged-in to (A). Both A and B are internal so a user needs to be authenticated in order to access them. Moreover, only specific users can use specific websites (B).

I'm looking for the best way of passing credentials of the user who accessed (A) to service (B) so that service (B) can authenticate that same user.

I thought about using mutual SSL for ensuring secure connection between (A) and (B). I'm a complete newbie in the world of network security, so I'd appreciate your opinions about it. Also, what libraries could I use? And how feasible would be passing certificate of a given user through my website (A) to (B) if I were to use mutual SSL for authenticating between the user and website (A) too?

Comment: Libraries for what language?

Comment: I need libraries for Java

Comment: I don't see why you need mutual authentication between A and B at all. You just need A to pass the clients original credentials to B. Mutual authentication between A and B doesn't accomplish that. And why the Kerberos tag?